# AS3 - Very large XML makes app freeze

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air

I'm making a dictionary and I have a little problem. My code does what it needs to do (look up the string entered in the XML), but I think I made it the wrong way. Here is my (commented) code, could you tell me if there is a better way (beginner here, so be patient :) ).

First the xml structure:

```
<dico>
    <word>
        <latin> symbols in latin alphabet</latin>
        <trad> traduction </trad>
        <type> noun, adj, adv, etc. </trad>
        <code> A1D3C1 </code> //what will be looked up
    </word>
<dico>
```

And the AS3 code:

```
//the xml file has been imported before
var queryCode:String; //variables used to store the XML data
var queryTranslitt:String;
var queryType:String;
var queryTrad:String;
var intIST:int;

function fnXML(dico: XML): void { //give the var the data taken from XML
    queryCode = dico.mot.code[intIST]
    queryTranslitt = dico.mot.translitteration[intIST];
    queryType = dico.mot.categorie[intIST];
    queryTrad = dico.mot.traduction[intIST];    
}

function fnQuery(e: Event): void { //compare the query variable to the XML

    for (var iSt: int = 0; iSt < 44823; iSt++) { //44823 is the number of
    // definitions in the XML file, that's probably the part that sucks.
        intIST = iSt;
        fnXML(myXML2);
        if (query == queryCode) { //query has been initialized before ofc)
            trace (queryCode);
            trace (queryTranslitt);
            trace (queryType);
            trace (queryTrad);
        }
    }
}
```

This code need to be executed EVERYTIME the user enters a letter (symbol really) (there are no spaces in the language so a long word can be several words). 
It works: i click on the first symbol ("i", which corresponds to 3 different words) and I get the traces of those words and their definitions, but the app freezes (i think because of the number of XML nodes it has to go through)
Anyone know a better way?
Thank you.

PS: By the way, I'm using Flash CC (Air for Android 17.0) if it helps.

Comment: Could you provide the XML file and a definition of your "glyphs"? I guess it's a letter plus a number, but am not sure, please clarify.

Comment: Here is the XML sample : https://mega.co.nz/#!GFpSWJgJ!QUS9RCfsbR0Reo3JxK5Tby1rPlmFVgEeqsueW8bUctU

Comment: As for the glyphs, they are hieroglyphs. The user has a list of hieroglyphs. He clicks the one he needs and the app converts it to its code (example, the sitting man hieroglyph becomes A1.) The codes can be 1 letter (A-Z), a number (1-500) and often another letter. For example, N150F would correspond to one hieroglyph. If he clicks 3 times on the sitting man hieroglyph, the query var will be A1A1A1. As A1A1A1 is a word, the dictionary will output "man, manking, people". Tell me if you need more infos, and thank you for your patience.

Comment: thanks. I have no time to play with this until next week. Is this some official format/encoding for hieroglyphs? In the meantime, see if you can serialize the data structure into a file, to speed up the build process of it, as suggested in my other comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy. Most people don't want to even try to use XML search methods because they don't understand them or don't know how to use them so they all end up with hash tables or loops. null solution would work but would still require a lot of computation to get the hash table set correctly in the first place. Instead do this:

```
var codeSearch:String = String(imput_txt.text);//get what's typed
//xml is your entire xml data
var xmlresult:XMLList = xml.word.(String(code).indexOf(codeSearch) >= 0)
//use xml serach method to find any code that contains the searh term
output_txt.text = "Found " + xmlresult.length() + " results";
//finally we get a xmlList back with either nothing or some result
//if xmlresult.length() > 0 then loop through it and do whatever.
```

Comment: It was indeed incredibly easy and it works perfectly. The results are shown in less than 1sec and are perfectly accurate! Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the right data structure could be helpful in your situation.

First of all, looping through the XML list seems to be the naive approach (not that you are naive in doing it, but in terms of, the simplest way that works and that frst comes to mind).

But you have some additional information:

> `A1D3C1`  //what will be looked up

You can exploit that, by storing your list in a hash map, based on the code. A generic `Object` provides such functionality.

```
var map:Object = {};
map["A1D3C1"] = {latin: "symbols in latin alphabet", trad: "traduction", type:"noun, adj, adv, etc."}
```

Please not that I am using a generic `Object` as the list to store all words. You could also use a `Dictionary`, which essentially does the same. Run some performance tests to see which is faster.

Also, each word in this list is represented as a generic `Object`. Maybe you are better off using a custom class.

You can go one step further and split the code into letters or characters. This means that you will end up with a tree structure. Each position introduces a new branch for every character used in a code in the XML file.

```
var map:Object = {};
map["A"] = {};
map["A"]["1"] = {};
// ...
map["A"]["1"]["D"]["3"]["C"]["1"] = {latin: "symbols in latin alphabet", trad: "traduction", type:"noun, adj, adv, etc."}
```

It is a significant effort to build this structure, but this only happens once, so you can do this at the start of the program. Of course you would do that programmatically based on the XML file and not hard coded as I did to illustrate.

I hope you can see the benefit of such a structure. If the user types "A", you will only operate on map["A"], which contains only a fraction of the total number of words.

What you so far considered to be a disadvantage:

> This code need to be executed EVERYTIME the user enters a letter (symbol really)
>   is actually rather helpful, because every given letter reduces the number of words that you have to look at.

It is up to you to test how much (if at all) this is faster, but my gut feeling tells me this could help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The tree structure method is going to be hard to implement in my case: the user never types "A" or "B", he chooses one of the 4000+ hieroglyphs, the hieroglyph is then transformed to a code that can be A1 or AA1 or A156 or Z20. continued>

Comment: <About the object method. I've created a Word class that contains the four  fields as variables. Having never worked with Objects before, I'm a bit lost. Should I push the data from the xml in the object like I would an array? (I've also tried to push the data in an array at launch, but it takes forever. When all the data is "uploaded" to the array, the dictionnary works perfectly in matters of seconds, but having a 2 minutes loading screen is not an option :s)

Comment: @Jeryl It's actually the same. You are just using a different (bigger) alphabet.  In this situation, the method provides the additional advantage that you can disable those hieroglyphs that aren't available, which improves the suer experience, as they cannot type a word that doesn't exist and spend less time searching through fewer hieroglyphs to choose from. simply substitute my single character letters with whatever you are using as letter, consisting of several characters. The custom class will not help you with this problem, I just mentioned it as an alternative

Comment: @Jeryl if it is applicable in your situation, you can try to serialize the Dictionary into a file. You would then load this file and deserialize the content back into a dictionary, ignoring the XML file that this was originally based upon. This means that you'd have to recreate the serialized file whenever you change the XML file, but it is probably quicker than rebuilding the datastructure from scratch every time.

Comment: I've accepted BotMaster answer, but I still wanted to thank you for helping. You've taught me quite all a lot :)